# How to get the button controls in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have 2 HTML files.

In First.html I want to include Second.html. When i click on Login button , I was uanble to get the data or control from the in js file.

**First.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>      
    <title>Insert title here</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.js'></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/first.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
     <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.js'></script>
</head>     
<body>      
<div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label id="luserid" ><strong>UserId : </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" value="" class="logon" placeholder="Username" required/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label id="lpassword"><strong>Password :</strong></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="logon" value="" placeholder="Password" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-body">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">                            
                <div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" id="loginbtn" data-theme="b">Login</a></div>                          
        </fieldset>
    </div>              
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**first.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
      $('#content').load('login.html');
      $("#loginbtn").click(function () {
          alert("Inside Login");
      });        
 });
```

Help me out on this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach the `click` handler inside a `load` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('#content').load('login.html', function() {
     $("#loginbtn").click(function () {
      alert("Inside Login");
     });        
  }
});
```

The reason your code fails, is because the `#loginbtn` element may not yet exist when you try to set the `click` handler.